How to stop "Powered by Admiral" anti ad-block pop-up messages?
I've recently noticed a TON of sites using this Admiral anti-ad-blocking software.



Your experience is important to us.
It looks like you are using an adblocker.
Disable Your Adblocker
Disable my adblocker
Already a Subscriber? Log In
Continue without disabling.
Powered By Admiral

The site loads normally, then this annoying Admiral pop-up loads a few seconds later.
I won't be disabling my content blocker to read these sites. Sometimes I can click "Continue without disabling", but sometimes that option does not appear.
How can I prevent these pop-ups via a browser extension?

The really funny thing is I usually see this on my phone... Which has no AdBlock. Hypothetically - would adblocking the AdBlock nags be acceptable?

No need for any additional extensions. Within your adblock extension subscribe to one or multiple anti-adblock lists like these Anti-Adblock Killer or EasyList ones, which include Admiral blocking and should be compatible with all the major adblockers. Other various lists can also be found.

I would also recommend running list(s) like that with uBlock Origin, which is the fastest and most reliable one by far. It gets rid of lots of annoying anti-adblock measures with default filters, it also attempts to fix some sites that don't like that. For remaining ones you could enable optional Annoyances type of list(s).
Just note that its support in a Chromium-based browser like Google Chrome might end anytime soon due to Manifest v3. There are e.g. registry workarounds for that though. Or you could try uBlock Origin Lite that has bunch of limitations compared to the original one, but it attempts to work around them.

I recently published a chrome extension AdBlock Detector Bypass by CPE, You can check it @ https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/adblock-detector-bypass-b/bffmkleioghafggghlaeemdgjpmbppii . All you have to do is click it once to activate, and it’ll automatically run in the background. It blocks or bypasses Admiral, along with a bunch of other AdBlock detectors used on various websites.

Oh, so you’re not the only person who finds those annoying :P
The first comment is spot on: just block the blocker of the blocker!
My personal favourite anti-adblocker remover is probably Anti-Adblock Killer. (It’s free and also an extension of uBlock Protector, I believe.)
I can first-hand tell you that it works 99% of the time on Admiral ones, too.

There is also PopUp Off, which also blocks the standard "Do you mind our [obnoxious] cookies?" popup... though this is not the site for software recommendations. The question and this answer and comment might better go on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

This (GitHub) is not maintained (last commit was in Nov 21, 2016, >7 years ago).

@xypha still works for me!
